# Fetch the name of a column with a variable in the corresponding row

Tags: sql, hive, case

I have a query which has columns going from `Jan-14` to `Dec-18` with rows highlighted by supplierIDs and their corresponding spend for the associated time period. I'm trying to create a case statement which will tell me the first month of spend when it's not equal to 0. I provided an example of what I have and what I'm trying to have it look like below:

Can someone please help?

```
Supplier ID Jan-14 Feb-14 Mar-14 Apr-14....Dec-18 FirstMonthSpend

00001         0      0     $10      0        0         Mar-14

00002         0     $10      0      0        0         Feb-14
```

Thanks so much in advance!

I also provided a screenshot of the data and the column I'm hoping to create in yellow.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEe2c.jpg)

Comment: If you're trying to create a case statement it sounds like your on the right path, why not share what you have written so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a giant `case` expression:

```
select supplierId,
       (case when "Jan-14" > 0 then 'Jan-14'
             when "Feb-14" > 0 then 'Feb-14'
             . . .
        end) as first_month
from t;
```

Note that you have a poor representation of the data.  You should have one row per supplier and per month.  If you had such a data model, the query would be much simpler.

Comment: Thanks so much for the initial response. The problem with a case statement is that a single row could have multiple values. I just want to know the placement of just the first value.

Comment: @user10349635 . . . The `case` expression does *exactly* what you want.  It returns the first non-zero value.

Comment: Gordon - Thank you for your help, I'm going to try your solution. I may have overthought it a bit.